# What does Facebook Login do in MW3 Multiplayer?

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3, facebook

I see there is a Facebook Login in the MW3 Multiplayer main menu and I wonder What it actually does.

Will I have to install a Facebook App in my Profile?

If it works as an announcer, can I set who sees my actions and to what extent?
For example: I want only my close friends and not my co-workers see my progress.
Is that how it works?

And one-nice to have: I see the login is not diverted to a browser but takes place in the client. What is the security situation here?
Can anyone network sniff and see if it is https?

Comment: Don't want your co-workers to see, huh? *ahem* Calling in 'sick' and don't want trophies to show up in your Facebook feed?

Comment: No, I just want to look cool when girls ask how my weekend was, and I tell them I was base-jumping in the Swiss Alps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UWNa108GXRA) was posted last week that describes Modern Warfare 3's Facebook integration. I believe mostly focuses on helping you to find games with your Facebook friends, but I'm not positive on that.

Comment: That video was removed by the user. Any other sources?

Comment: @Bora I found the video on YouTube, and updated the link.