# How Do I Chat with my Twitch.tv viewers in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, streaming

I am streaming my Minecraft game using the built-in Twitch.tv integration. I would like to chat with my stream viewers directly from Minecraft, but I don't know if it is possible, or how.

Comment: For future reference, there is a [Stack Exchange for Web Applications](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/) where you can ask about Twitch and other such services.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a website rather than playing a game.

Comment: To my understanding, Minecraft now has a feature about streaming to Twitch.  I don't know that from personal experience, but I believe there's been some mention of it.

Comment: @Frank and other games integrate with Facebook, but that does not make Arqade the place for Facebook questions.

Comment: @Batophobia If it happens in the game, I think it can be reasonably expected for it to be within our expertise.  I'm not saying we should answer every Twitch question; just those as happen to actually be happening within a game.

Comment: @Batophobia It's built-in to newer editions of minecraft, and we do answer questions like http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/34621/14289 regarding facebook integration built into games, so...

Comment: I disagree with the notion that this is a webapp-question. Newer Minecraft-Version have a built-in twitch.tv integration, and this question is likely about just that, rather than the website, and thus can only be properly answered on Arqade, rather than Webapps SE. That being said, this question actually has been [asked and answered](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/146593/how-do-i-send-twitch-tv-chat-messages-in-minecraft?rq=1) before, albeit with clearer wording as to the intent. So this question should be closed as duplicate rather than off-topic.

Comment: @z' There's an in-game stream button to automatically set up a stream. It USES the Twitch system, but the host doesn't need to even touch the Twitch website to start a stream and the stream chat appears in-game. As the streaming is integrated pretty much entirely into the game, and an ingame solution could be expected (although not currently possible), I think the question fits better here than the Web App site.

Comment: @MrLemon I interpreted the original version "how to chat with stream viewers on Twitch.tv" as using the web service.  If it is actually about using Minecraft User Interface, then yes this is appropriate for Arqade.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the simplest solution: Messages from the chat will appear on your screen. If you are recording your voice, the chat users can hear your replies via your stream. So just answer out loud, no mod required.

(If not recording your voice, you can similarly type into the in-game chat so it appears on the video stream).

Answer (score 0):

If you have another monitor or another computer you can open up your Dashboard on Twitch, pause the video (to eliminate excess bandwidth usage) and simply chat there.

After a quick google I also found this: http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/1610516-15-and-up-forge-twitchtv-irc-mod-v29-twitchtv-chat-ingame/

I cant attest to how good it is, but if it does what it says, sounds useful.

Comment: My bad, didn't realize the game could have a bearing on the answer.  re-added the tag.

Comment: @GnomeSlice No worries